# SQL Query to get all the ancestors of a node , in a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following structure

- `Child_id`
- `Parent_Id`
- `Child_name`
- `Parent_name`
- `Child_Description`

I want a query to get all the parents of all leaf level nodes in a single row.

For eg : If `X` and `Y` are leaf level nodes in the following:

```
A->B->C->D->X

F->G->H->I->Y
```

The query should return 2 rows as following

```
Child Parent1 Parent2 Parent3 Parent4
X  D  C  B  A
Y  I  H  G  F
```

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (sql server, postgres, oracle, etc..)?  What is the maximum number of parents you would anticipate being returned for any child?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote that did not return your expected output?

Comment: Sorry to have missed it, but its oracle RDBM that I am using.

Comment: And the maximum number of expected parents are fixed at 5.

Comment: The column `Parent_Id` is a foreign key to the same table?

Comment: Please add some data of your table(s)

Comment: the structure as provided above is basically a result set from join from a couple of tables using the following   .... START WITH I_PARENT_MEMBER_ID=I_TOP_MEMBER_ID
CONNECT BY PRIOR I_CHILD_MEMBER_ID=I_PARENT_MEMBER_ID ..... I basically have been able to achieve the basic parent-child relationship using this query but want to modify this result set further to have all the ancestors in a single row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this make any sense?

```
SQL> with test (child_id, parent_id) as
  2    (select 'x', 'd'  from dual union all
  3     select 'd', 'c'  from dual union all
  4     select 'c', 'b'  from dual union all
  5     select 'b', 'a'  from dual union all
  6     select 'a', null from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 'y', 'i'  from dual union all
  9     select 'i', 'h'  from dual union all
 10     select 'h', 'g'  from dual union all
 11     select 'g', 'f'  from dual union all
 12     select 'f', null from dual
 13    ),
 14  anc as
 15    (select sys_connect_by_path(child_Id, '>') pth
 16     from test
 17     where connect_by_isleaf = 1
 18     connect by prior child_id = parent_id
 19     start with parent_id is null
 20    )
 21  select regexp_substr(pth, '[^>]+', 1, 5) c1,
 22         regexp_substr(pth, '[^>]+', 1, 4) c2,
 23         regexp_substr(pth, '[^>]+', 1, 3) c3,
 24         regexp_substr(pth, '[^>]+', 1, 2) c4,
 25         regexp_substr(pth, '[^>]+', 1, 1) c5
 26  from anc;

C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
-- -- -- -- --
x  d  c  b  a
y  i  h  g  f

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `test` CTE simulates your data (at least, I think so)
- `anc`(estors) CTE selects the "longest" path because `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` shows whether current row can (or can not) be expanded any further. If it returns `1`, it can not.
- the *final* query uses regular expressions to convert a CSV string (delimiter is `>` in my example; could be something else) into columns. There's nothing dynamic in it, so - if data you have is different from up to 5 "columns", you'd have to fix it

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, that really helped. :)